# Adding unsupported Framework to project

Tags: iphone, frameworks

I'm trying to add new library to my project. This library contains code to deal with bar code scanning and uses CoreVideoFramework which was introduced in iOS 4.0. Currently I had my iOS deployment target set to 3.1.2 to support those devices. But now when I try to run new version of application on iPhone with 3.1.2 it crashes at very beginning saying it can't find CoreVideoFramework. On 4.2 simulator everything work fine.

I'm wondering if it is possible to add CoreVideoFramework to project without crashes on 3.x devices. I'm thinking about a situation when on 3.x BarCodeScanning is turned off and on 4.x it is enabled.

Simply I'm trying to avoid requesting from user to have iOS 4.x. I want my app to still support 3.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible

In your target settings go to "Link with libraries" section and for CoreVideo.framework set link option to "Optional" (by default it is "Required").